# Which version of this upcoming beer app UI do you think is more effective and why?

Tags: layout, color-combination

I am trying to decide which version of my layout to go with from a color and post layout perspective. Any reasoning for your choice would be really helpful!

http://forrst-production.s3.amazonaws.com/posts/snaps/94885/original.png?1310526224

Comment: Can you try being a bit more specific? What are your thoughts on the different variations? What are you going for? What kind of audience? Have you done any testing?

Answer (score 3):

The third option. It has a more harmonius color palette and the links on the post title have much better affordance.

Answer (score 2):

The third one - the link colour matches the 'I'm drinking' button, and the border around the entry is good. It seems less noisy than the others. Is the bg colour paler on the third or is it my lcd screen. It looks nicer paler :-)

Answer (score 2):

Third option - Each entry is clearly defined and the clickable elements are obviously so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say the first one, it shares the benefits of the third option but I prefer that links are brown rather than than red. Red has been used for the main call to action button and is often associated with errors.